# Content of floated sidebar going to main container

Tags: html, css

Say I have this html:

```
<div id="sidebar">
 TestTestTestTestTestTest
</div>
<div id="content">
 Content
</div>
```

And this CSS:

```
#sidebar {
 float:left;
 width:15%;    
 border:1px solid red;
}
#content {
 float:left;
    width:75%;
    border:1px solid green;
}
```

As you can see [here](http://jsfiddle.net/t4rNp/) , the content on the sidebar is going under the content container.  How can I avoid that so that it would break a line and continue in the sidebar?

​
[image: Overlap content]

Comment: Looks fine to me - what browser are you looking at it in? IE?

Comment: Chrome and firefox...Edited question with screenshot. Make the width small...

Comment: Sorry I take it back - it's because you have one continuous line of text that is too big for it's containing element. You wouldn't have that normally would you? There would be spaces between the words. I only see it messed up in IE and Chrome - looks fine in Firefox. Play about with the overflow property on sidebar to resolve it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not manage text if there are no white spaces.

You can avoid at this issue adding the **ellipsis** on the `#sidebar`:

```
overflow: hidden;
text-overflow: ellipsis;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/t4rNp/3/

Comment: That is not true i think. Word-wrap:break-word is specifically which deals with this kind of issue.

Comment: it create a second line and break your text. I never used it.

Comment: How can I avoid that so that it would break a line and continue in the sidebar?  << This is what he said. No issues though, happens ;)

Comment: In fact, no solution. The best to see is the ellipsis.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 methods :

1 ) Add

> word-wrap:break-word;

in your #sidebar. Because TestTestTestTest is a single word you need to apply the css i mentioned.

[Description about word-wrap](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_text-overflow.asp)

2) Add

> overflow: hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis;

to #sidebar. This method though wont break the line.

[Description about text-overflow](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_text-overflow.asp)

Answer (score 0):

Your text is wider than the width of the container, and is overflowing into the adjacent div.

ie: TestTestTestTestTest > 15% width

Changing the content within the sidebar div to just Test for example will stop the text overlapping the adjacent div.

I'd look to change the overflow of the div to hidden so that any text that doesn't fit within the box will not be shown, rather than overflowing.